# How to stop Jquery dropdown from scrolling with page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So im having a problem with a Jquery dropdown, where if i scroll down the page, the dropdown will appear farther down rather then where they should be directly under the button..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="/Nexus 5/Website style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeoutID;
$(function(){
    $('.dropdown').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.sublinks').stop(false, true).hide();
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        var submenu = $(this).parent().next();

        submenu.css({
            position:'absolute',
            top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 'px',
            left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
            zIndex:1000
        });

        submenu.stop().slideDown(300);

        submenu.mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).slideUp(300);
        });

        submenu.mouseenter(function(){
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        });

    });
    $('.dropdown').mouseleave(function(){
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {$('.sublinks').stop(false, true).slideUp(300);}, 250);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" style="position: fixed; ">
    <img src="smalllogo.png" style="float:left; width:180px; height:73px;">
      <div class="nav">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a  href="Nexus 5/Nexus 5 (home).html" class="dropdown" >Nexus 5</a></li>
                <li class="sublinks">
                    <a href="Nexus 5/Nexus 5 (info).html">Info</a>
                    <a href="Nexus 5/Nexus 5 (root & unlock).html">Root & Unlock</a>
                    <a href="Nexus 5/Nexus 5 (recovery).html">Recoveries</a>
                    <a href="Nexus 5/Nexus 5 (roms).html">ROMs</a>
                    <a href="Nexus 5/Nexus 5 (kernels).html">Kernels</a>
                    <a href="Nexus 5/Nexus 5 (other).html">Other</a>
                </li>
            <li><a href="Galaxy S4/GS4 (home).html" class="dropdown">Galaxy S4</a></li>
            <li class="sublinks">
                <a href="Galaxy S4/GS4 (info).html">Info</a>
                <a href="Galaxy S4/GS4 (root & unlock).html">Root & Unlock</a>
                <a href="Galaxy S4/GS4 (recovery).html">Recoveries</a>
                <a href="Galaxy S4/GS4 (roms).html">ROMs</a>
                <a href="Galaxy S4/GS4 (other).html">Other</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Normal]

Then when rolling over, and scrolled down, the jquery links go way down the page.

This can be viewed live from androiddevelopmentdepot.com

Comment: why are you applying an offset to the `top` property of the submenu?

Comment: It does not happen here, what browser/OS are you using. It is fine  in Win/Chrome (last build)

Comment: @GiuseppeR It happens in all browsers. Hover over a menu to see a submenu, take your mouse off the menu, then scroll down a very little amount. Place your mouse back on the menu again, the sub menu will have moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't understand why you're calculating the top position of it. Fixing top, could solve your problem?

Try this:

```
submenu.css({
    position:'absolute',
    top: 75,
    left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
    zIndex:1000
});
```

Comment: default top is 70px by the way